# Find a permutation $x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)}$ of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that maximises $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\vert x_{\sigma(k)}-x_{\sigma(k+1)}\vert.$

Tags: real-analysis, algorithms, discrete-optimization, rearrangement-inequality

Suppose $\ x_1,\ x_2,\ \ldots,\ x_n\ $ are real numbers with $\ x_1 < x_2 <\ldots < x_n.$

Is there an efficient way to find a permutation $\ x_{\sigma(1)},\ x_{\sigma(2)},\ \ldots,\ x_{\sigma(n)}\ $ of $\ x_1,\ x_2,\ \ldots,\ x_n\ $ which maximises $\ f\left(\ \left( x_{\sigma(1)},\ x_{\sigma(2),\ \ldots,\ x_{\sigma(k)} } \right)\ \right) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\vert x_{\sigma(k)} - x_{\sigma(k+1)} \right\vert\ ? $

My intuition tells me that either $\ f(\ \left(x_1,\ x_n,\ x_2,\ x_{n-1},\ x_3,\ x_{n-2},\ \ldots)\ \right)\ $ or $\ f(\ \left(x_n,\ x_1,\ x_{n-1},\ x_2,\ x_{n-2},\ x_3,\ \ldots\ \right)\ )\ $ might be a maximum, but I am not sure about this or how to prove if this is true.

Edit: my intuition is wrong. For example, take $\ x_1= 1,\ x_2 = 2,\ x_3=3,\ x_4=4.$ Then neither $\ x_1\to x_4\to x_2 \to x_3,\ $ nor $\ x_4\to x_1 \to x_3\to x_2\ $ are the longest route (both have length $6$), since $\ x_3\to x_1\to x_4\to x_2\ $ is longer with length $7$.

Comment: Before attempting a proof, you could do computer simulations in order to be certain that your intuition is right...

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: I've seen a common theme in these cases, called exchange arguments : given a permutation $\sigma$ and associating to it a cost function $C_{\sigma}$ which you need to minimize, *sometimes* what happens is that if you want to make a conjecture on $\sigma$, you can prove that for any $\sigma$ that doesn't follow that conjecture, there is a $\sigma'$ with a smaller associated cost. The reason for the word "exchange" is that $\sigma'$ is usually just two elements of $\sigma$ swapped with each other or shifted, so it's not really very far from $\sigma$. See if you can try something like this.

Comment: To bolster the above argument, consider what happens when you exchange consecutive indices of a permutation. That gives you a new permutation. Compare the cost (in this case, reward, since you're maximizing the objective function) function of the two permutations, and find a simple condition that will tell you which is better. Now, an optimal permutation must be one where no such swaps can possibly be made.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I know what you are talking about, although sometimes those types of arguments don't work, because while it might be true for an exchange between two objects, that doesn't imply if it works when you exchange three objects between each other (e.g. clockwise). But sometimes the argument works (it depends on the problem), so I'll give it a try.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Sure, let me know how it goes. I'm also working parallelly on the question, with the intention of seeing if the swap argument is helpful.

Comment: I found [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/finding-a-permutation-p-of-x-1-x-2-dots-x-n-which-maximises-sum-i-1) very similar problem. Since there's no duplicate on MSE, I might think of posting an answer with all the research in that post bundled into one. For one, there is no complete solution available there but a clear indication that the exchange argument can work.

Comment: I have had a look at your exchanges: the swapping idea is good but what prevents you to be catched into a local max ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Your point is very good because in the post I linked above the accepted answer shows four local maxima for a particular choice of $x_i$. This still narrows your search for global maxima to a smaller pool of "possible" local maxima. because I believe we can write down a structure theorem for local maxima. Furthermore, I'm convinced that we can write down conditions for the initial set under which the function admits a unique local maxima, as well.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is YES, there is an efficient algorithm. Initially there are $n!$ candidates to test for maximality, but I show below that you can limit the search to just a special set of at most $n+1$ permutations (see the corollary at the end of this answer), which gives us linear complexity.

Intuitively, it seems that the logical way to construct a solution $\sigma$ is to define successively $\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\ldots,\sigma(n)$ in such a way that at each stage, $\sigma(j)$ is the farthest possible from $\sigma(j-1)$ among the remaining allowed values, in order to maximize the summand $|\sigma(j)-\sigma(j-1)|$ (and this idea turns out to be partially correct and leads to an efficient algorithm as I am going to explain).

If we apply this construction to the initial seed $\sigma(1)=k,\sigma(2)=n$, (where $1\leq k \leq n$), we obtain a permutation $\alpha_{n,k}$, going $(k,n,1,n-1,2,n-2,\ldots )$ and uniquely defined by

$$
\alpha_{n,k}(t)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
k & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ j=1 \\
j-1 & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ 1\lt j\leq k \\
j & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ k\lt j \\
n+1-j & \textrm{if} & t=2j, \ 1\lt j\leq n-k \\
n-j & \textrm{if} & t=2j, \ n-k\lt j \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{1}
$$

where some cases may be empty according to the values of $k$. It must be emphasized that (1) above rigourously defines a unique permutation of $[|1..n|]$
for every $k\in [|1..n|]$, even on the edge cases $k=1$ or $n$ (to check that $\alpha_{n,k}$ is always a permutation, notice that the second and fifth cases together define a bijection with image $[|1..(r-1)|]$, while the third and fourth together define a bijection with image $[|(r+1)..n|]$).

Similarly, the initial seed $\sigma(1)=k,\sigma(2)=1$ leads to a permutation $\beta_{n,k}$, going $(k,1,n,2,n-1,\ldots )$ and uniquely defined by

$$
\beta_{n,k}(t)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
k & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ j=1 \\
n+2-j & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ 1\lt j\leq n-r+1 \\
n+1-j & \textrm{if} & t=2j-1, \ n-r+1\lt j \\
j & \textrm{if} & t=2j, \ 1\lt j\lt k \\
j+1 & \textrm{if} & t=2j, \ k\leq j \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$

Let us introduce some more notation. Let $x\in{\mathbb R}$, and $Y$ be a finite set of $m\geq 2$ numbers, $Y=\lbrace y_1 \lt y_2 \lt \ldots \lt y_m \rbrace$, and let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $[|1..m|]$.

Define

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
W'(Y,\sigma) & = & \sum_{j=2}^{m} |y_{\sigma(j)}-y_{\sigma(j+1)}| \\
W^{-}(x,Y,\sigma) & = & -(x-y_{\sigma(1)})+W'(Y,\sigma) \\
W^{+}(x,Y,\sigma) & = & \ (x-y_{\sigma(1)})+W'(Y,\sigma) \\
W(x,Y,\sigma) & = & \ |x-y_{\sigma(1)}|+W'(Y,\sigma)=\max(W^{-}(x,Y,\sigma),W^{+}(x,Y,\sigma))
\end{array}\tag{3}
$$

We will also write $\mu_{m}(Y)$ for the "center" of $Y$, namely $\mu_{m}$ is the middle element $y_{p}$ if $m=2p+1$ is odd, and is the mean $\frac{y_{p}+y_{p+1}}{2}$ if $m=2p$ is even.

Then we have :

**Main theorem.** Consider the problem of maximizing, for fixed $x,m,Y$, the expression $G(\sigma)=W(x,Y,\sigma)$. If $x\leq \mu_{m}(Y)$, then the maximum is attained at $B_m=\beta_{m,m}$ and equals $G(\beta_{m,m})=W^{-}(x,Y,\beta_{m,m})$. We denote this number by $M^{\beta}_m$. If $x\geq \mu_{m}(Y)$, then the maximum is attained at $A_m=\alpha_{m,1}$ and equals $G(\alpha_{m,1})=W^{+}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,1})$. We denote this number by $M^{\alpha}_m$.

**Proof of main theorem.** We argue by induction on $m\geq 2$. In the base case $m=2$, there are only two permutations, $A_2$ the identity and $B_2$ the transposition that exchanges $1$ and $2$ ; now $W(x,Y,A_2)=|x-y_1|+|y_2-y_1|$ and
$W(x,Y,B_2)=|x-y_2|+|y_2-y_1|$ and $\mu_2=\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$ ; the result is now clear.

Suppose that the result holds for $m-1$, and let us try to show the result for $m$. Let $\sigma$ be an arbitrary permutation of $[|1..m|]$. We must show that
$G(\sigma) \leq M^{\beta}_m$ when $y\leq \mu_m(Y)$ and $G(\sigma) \leq M^{\alpha}_m$ when $y\geq \mu_m(Y)$. Let $k=\sigma(1)$ and $Y'=Y\setminus \lbrace y_{k} \rbrace$ ; this has cardinality $m-1$, so we can write it as $Y'=\lbrace y'_1 \lt y'_2 \lt \ldots \lt y'_{m-1} \rbrace$. Then, we can write

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
W(x,Y,\sigma) &=& |x-y_{\sigma(1)}|+\sum_{j=2}^{m}|y_{\sigma(j)}-y_{\sigma(j+1)}| \\ 
&=& |x-y_{k}|+|y_{k}-y'_{\tau(1)}|+\sum_{j=2}^{m-1}|y'_{\tau(j)}-y'_{\tau(j+1)}| \\ 
&=& |x-y_{k}|+W(y_{k},Y',\tau),
\end{array}\tag{4}
$$

where $\tau$ is some permutation of $[|1..(m-1)|]$ which we needn't write out here. By the induction hypothesis,

$$
W(x,Y,\sigma) \leq |x-y_k| + 
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
W(y_{k},Y',B_{m-1}) &\textrm{if}& y_k \leq \mu_{m-1}(Y') \\ 
W(y_{k},Y',A_{m-1}) &\textrm{if}& y_k \geq \mu_{m-1}(Y')
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}
$$

or in other words,

$$
W(x,Y,\sigma) \leq 
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}
W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &\textrm{if}& y_k \leq \mu_{m-1}(Y') \\ 
W(x,Y,\beta_{m,k}) &\textrm{if}& y_k \geq \mu_{m-1}(Y')
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}
$$

Supoose first that $k\lt \frac{m+1}{2}$. Then we have both $y_k\leq \mu_{m-1}(Y')$ and $y_k\leq \mu_{m}(Y)$, so we are necessarily in the first case of (6) above, so that $W(x,Y,\sigma) \leq W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})$. If $x\leq y_k$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\beta}_m-W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,B_m) - W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{-}(x,Y,B_m) - W^{-}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& 2(\mu_m(Y)-y_k) \geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{7}
$$

Next, if $y_k \leq x \leq \mu_m(Y)$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\beta}_m-W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,B_m) - W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{-}(x,Y,B_m) - W^{+}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& 2(\mu_m(Y)-x) \geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{8}
$$

Finally, if $\mu_m(Y) \leq x$, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\alpha}_m-W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,A_m) - W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{+}(x,Y,A_m) - W^{+}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& 0.
\end{array}\tag{9}
$$

This finishes the case $k\lt \frac{m+1}{2}$. The case $k\gt \frac{m+1}{2}$ is symmetric, so we are left with the case $k=\frac{m+1}{2}$, or
$m=2k-1$. Then $\mu_{m}(Y)=y_k$ and $\mu_{m-1}(Y')=\frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$. Our argument will go by a disjunction of $2\times 2=4$ cases, as we need to consider both the position of $x$ wrt $y_k$ (to know whether our wished upper bound is $M^{\alpha}_m$ or $M^{\beta}_m$)  and the position of $y_k$ wrt $\frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$ (to know which alternative of (6) holds).

If $x \leq y_k$ and $y_k \leq \frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$, then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\beta}_m-W(x,Y,\beta_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,B_m) - W(x,Y,\beta_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{-}(x,Y,B_m) - W^{-}(x,Y,\beta_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& y_{k+1}-y_{k}\geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{10}
$$

If $x \leq y_k$ and $y_k \geq \frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$, then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\beta}_m-W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,B_m) - W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{-}(x,Y,B_m) - W^{-}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& y_k-y_{k-1}\geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{11}
$$

If $x \geq y_k$ and $y_k \leq \frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$, then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\alpha}_m-W(x,Y,\beta_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,A_m) - W(x,Y,\beta_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{+}(x,Y,A_m) - W^{+}(x,Y,\beta_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& y_{k+1}-y_{k}\geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{12}
$$

If $x \geq y_k$ and $y_k \geq \frac{y_{k-1}+y_{k+1}}{2}$, then

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
M^{\alpha}_m-W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) &=& W(x,Y,A_m) - W(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k})  \\ 
&=&  W^{+}(x,Y,A_m) - W^{+}(x,Y,\alpha_{m,k}) \\ 
&=& y_{k}-y_{k-1}\geq 0.
\end{array}\tag{13}
$$

The main theorem is proved.

**Corollary (of main theorem).** For a finite set $X=\lbrace x_1 \lt x_2 \lt \ldots \lt x_n \rbrace$ and a permutation $\sigma$ of $[|1..n|]$, let $F(\sigma)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{\sigma(j)}-x_{\sigma(j-1)}|$.

Let $\Sigma_n$ be the set of the permutations defined by

$$
\Sigma_n= \bigg\lbrace \alpha_{n,j} \ \bigg| \ 1 \leq j \leq \frac{n+1}{2} \bigg\rbrace
\bigcup \bigg\lbrace \beta_{n,j} \ \bigg| \ \frac{n+1}{2} \leq j \leq n \bigg\rbrace \tag{14}
$$

(where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are defined by (1) and (2) ; thus $\Sigma_n$ containes $n$ elements when $n$ is even and $n+1$ elements when $n$ is odd). Then the maximum of $F$ is attained at least once on $\Sigma_n$.

For example, when $n=4$, you only need to consider the permutations $(1,4,2,3)$, $(2,4,1,3)$, $(3,1,4,2)$ and $(4,1,3,2)$.

Comment: Corr blimey! It might take a while to read this. Thank you for your large effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this as a maximum traveling salesman problem in which the customers are located on a number line and the cost to and from a dummy depot is $0$.

See [Mathematics Magazine Problem 1654](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219092?seq=4#metadata_info_tab_contents) for a similar problem where the depot is the origin and customer $k$ is located $k$ units to the right of the depot.

Comment: I don't know how to access Problem $1654$ in the link.

Comment: Maybe this OEIS entry (which also contains the link) will suffice: https://oeis.org/A092186

Comment: See this [student work](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_etd/send_file/send?accession=auhonors1494006002818757&disposition=inline) generalizing the reference you have given.